# Save value in angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have ui-grid that works fine ,the grid use server side pagination and there are view button to show details of the row in details page ,when I go back the grid render and show the first page in grid,I want to show current page before redirect to details page.

Example

If current page is 10 and I use  details button ,when I go back grid display page 1,but I need to render page in page 10

I'm thinking in saving page number in angular service but can't implement this.

Can anyone help me please how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can save data in services for use anywhere in your app:

```
app.service('svc', function() {
    var currentPage;

    return {
        setCurrentPage(value) {
            currentPage = value;
        },
        getCurrentPage() {
            return currentPage;
        }
    };
});
```

If you want the page number to persist even after a full page reload, you could use html `web storage`, or cookies.